# Adjusting legend layout for multiple legends associated to one Python plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, legend

I am creating a Python plot from a dataframe with 3 y-axes. For each y-axis, there are multiple y-values I want to plot. All data sets for the y-axes are plotted against a shared Date x-axis.

The code looks as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'test.xlsx', sheet_name='test', engine='openpyxl')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax3 = ax.twinx()
rspine = ax3.spines['right']
rspine.set_position(('axes', 1.15))
ax3.set_frame_on(True)
ax3.patch.set_visible(False)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)

ax.plot(df['Date'], df['Gas1'], label="Gas1", color='g')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['Gas2'], label="Gas2", color='b')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['Gas3'], label="Gas3", marker="o", markersize=2, color='r')
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Gas Rate")

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df['Date'], df['Water1'], label="Water1", color='k')
ax2.plot(df['Date'], df['Water2'], label="Water2", color='y')
ax2.set_ylabel("Water")

ax3.plot(df['Date'], df['Pressure1'], label="Pressure1")
ax3.plot(df['Date'], df['Pressure2'], label="Pressure2")
ax3.set_ylabel("Pressure")

ax.legend()
ax2.legend()
ax3.legend()
plt.show()
```

The problem I am having is that I want the legends to be **outside of the plot**, preferably on the right-hand side after the 2nd y-axis. Is this possible? Right now the legends are just overlayed on the plot and not fully visible. I have tried using bbox_to_anchor and loc functions but had no luck. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` collects all the legend handles and their labels. Combining those for each of the axes, a new legend can be created.

`bbox_to_anchor=` sets an anchor point for the legend, using [axes coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). `loc=` needs to be set, to tell which point of the legend's box will get fixed by the anchor.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('20210401', periods=30, freq='D'),
                   'Gas1': np.random.randn(30).cumsum(),
                   'Gas2': np.random.randn(30).cumsum(),
                   'Gas3': np.random.randn(30).cumsum(),
                   'Water1': np.random.randn(30).cumsum(),
                   'Water2': np.random.randn(30).cumsum(),
                   'Pressure1': np.random.randn(30).cumsum(),
                   'Pressure2': np.random.randn(30).cumsum()})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax3 = ax.twinx()
rspine = ax3.spines['right']
rspine.set_position(('axes', 1.15))
ax3.set_frame_on(True)
ax3.patch.set_visible(False)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)

ax.plot(df['Date'], df['Gas1'], label="Gas1", color='g')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['Gas2'], label="Gas2", color='b')
ax.plot(df['Date'], df['Gas3'], label="Gas3", marker="o", markersize=2, color='r')
ax.set_ylabel("Gas Rate")
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df['Date'], df['Water1'], label="Water1", color='k')
ax2.plot(df['Date'], df['Water2'], label="Water2", color='y')
ax2.set_ylabel("Water")

ax3.plot(df['Date'], df['Pressure1'], label="Pressure1")
ax3.plot(df['Date'], df['Pressure2'], label="Pressure2")
ax3.set_ylabel("Pressure")

handles1, labels1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles3, labels3 = ax3.get_legend_handles_labels()

ax.legend(handles=handles1 + handles2 + handles3,
          labels=labels1 + labels2 + labels3,
          bbox_to_anchor=(1.28, 1.02), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: combining 3 legends into one external legend]